# Grails copy resources to external dir

Tags: grails, resources

I would like to copy all the resources (js, css, bundles) created from grails (and its plugins cache, gzip, etc..) into an external folder (in S3) instead of inside the war.
Is it possible?
I've tried to check inside the documentation but with no result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use grails.war.resources to customize war content. Take a look at [section 18 of grails manual](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#deployment).

Comment: Can you explain better what are you looking for?

Comment: have an external folder which is used from a web server to serve all the static files, and all these files (created by Grails) are copied there automatically when the application is build

Comment: And you are not able to copy this files using the  grails.war.resources closure. That closure let you copy any file inside the war in a location you choose. If the files are not inside the war because runtime o startime generated the problem is different. You have to look inside the plugin configuration to change the location where that temporay files are stored

Comment: I want that all the less files transformed in css, zipped, bundled and renamed by the plugins are copied in another server rather than the one with the application server, to do this I need to process all the files generated by the resource plugin...but I don't know how...

Comment: Have you tried changing grails.resources.work.dir and grails.resources.uri.prefix as explained here? http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/guide/9.%20Configuration.html

Comment: mmm I can do it with it...the problem is that it does it at runtime...thanks